# Where to set Authorization Code in Facebook BOT

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-messenger, messenger

I am trying to get account linking work in my facebook bot. 
According to this url [FB Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/account-linking/authentication) developers are supposed to register an **authorization_code** and on succesfull login need to pass it as a param along with the redirect URI. But following is not mentioned

- How to generate authorization_token ? Some specific method or a random number ? or is it the access token of registered FB Page ?
- How to register authorize_token

Comment: so when the user logs in code redirects the user to the redirect_uri and i append a random authorization_code to it ?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use any **authorization_code** you like.
2. You don't need to register your authorize_token

Comment: But how do i register authorization_code in first place ?